# First time ever creating a Terrain

Tags: c++, opengl, physx

First night at taking a look at different ways to create Terrain.

I'm wanting to work on a racing project and was wondering if there was a way to create a 3D race track some how.

We plan on using C++, and are also using PhysX and openGL. Where should I be looking for creating Terrain? Also, does anyone know of some good Tutorials/Tips that can help me :)

Thanks

Comment: Which graphics library are you using? Normally you generate a mesh with different levels-of-detail out of a height map. I don't mean to be rude or a downer, but from the sounds of it you've never made a game before. If that's the case, you're already in over your head; you should start with something simpler like Pong, and work your way up. Game programming is not trivial.

Comment: Then a common way is to use height-maps and generate a mesh, like I said. Google will provide more info than I could.

Comment: No problem. If you ever hit a snag come back and we'll help with that specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic way to make terrain is by using a height-map, and generating a mesh out of it. Google will have [more information](http://www.google.com/search?q=opengl+terrain&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) than I can [give you](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/list.asp?categoryid=188).

By the way, **avoid going to Lighthouse3D right now**; it's been hacked and crashes your browser. Here's a [cached version](http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:WM-3iPEPhaIJ:www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/terrain/index.php3%3Fheightmap+opengl+terrain&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) that may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Great tutorial for creating tarrain here:

http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/terrain.html

It's DirectX specific but has enough general information to help you understand the theory.

The site also has other details on game making and is written by a British Games Programming lecturer - well worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you should create the appropriate meshes with blender (or another 3D modeling tool), which you will then import within your game. Using height maps is nice and all, but I think it's totally inappropriate for the kind of game you are interested in doing.

By using Blender/etc, you will also be able to add extra objects to your map like gates/checkpoints really easily and precisely.